# Javascript set hidden field value from another field not working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hidden field which should get the string value from a div and all is fine when working in browser, but it doesn't work when i run it on tablet or a smartphone. I don't get this.

here is my div and hidden field:

```
div id="signature-div" style="border: dotted 2px grey;">
    <div id="canvas"></div>
</div>

<input name="signature" type="hidden" id="signature" value="">
```

and the function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // signature
    var W = $("#signature-div").width();
    var sigCanvas = $("#canvas").jSignature({width: W, height: 180, "background-color":"#ddd"});

    // after signing the offer set hidden field value to signature
    $(document).on('mouseup', '#canvas',function(){
    //$("form").submit(function() {
        var rawSig = $("#canvas").jSignature("getData","svg");
        //$("#img").attr("data", 'data:' + rawSig);

        //$("#signature").val('data:' + rawSig);
        document.getElementById("signature").value = 'data:' + rawSig;

        // i have tried both of these up and it doesn't set the hidden value on mobile devices...is there something i'm missing here?

    });

});
```

Comment: You do it on `mouseup`... Tablets and smartphones do not have a mouse. Try to just add the `touchend` event to your script... Like this : `$(document).on('mouseup touchend', '#canvas',function(){`

Comment: you were right, just make an answer out of it and i will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do your "get string value" on `mouseup`...

Tablets and smartphones do not have a mouse.
Try to just add the `touchend` event to your script... Like this :

```
$(document).on('mouseup touchend', '#canvas',function(){
```

Also check for the other [touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent).
;)

Answer (score 1):

Devices with no mouse will never trigger a 'mouseup' event

Add the 'touchend' event also:

```
$(document).on('mouseup touchend', '#canvas',function(){
...
```

Comment: sorry the user @Louys Patrice Bessette was first! even though you both are right